# How can I transfer elasticsearch data from one data directory to another?

Tags: elasticsearch

Scenario:
I changed the default data directory of elasticsearch to something else and started indexing data without restarting the server. It turns out that it kept indexing data in the default directory (/var/lib/elasticsearch) instead of the new directory. After a routine server restart, it shifted to the new directory and now most of our data is placed in the default directory and some of it is placed in the new directory.

How can I merge the data present in the old directory with the data present in the new one? The elasticsearch version is of course the same.

Comment: "I changed the default data directory of elasticsearch to something else" - what exactly did you do ? change the `path.data` in elasticsearch.yml ? See: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/moving-data-directory-td4030005.html

Comment: Yes, I changed the path.data. The problem is that the data is placed in both locations. I cannot just copy old data to the new directory because that would overwrite existing data there. I have to somehow merge the data.

Comment: Did you try to create a [snapshot](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) and then restore it?

Answer (score 0):

In ElasticSearch 5.6 Edit below files.

1. `cat /etc/default/elasticsearch | grep -i DATA_DIR'DATA_DIR=/mnt/elasticsearch`
2. `cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service | grep -i Environment=DATA_DIR=/mnt/elasticsearch`

Restart the service

```
systemctl daemon-reload 
systemctl restart elasticsearch.service
```